# net-sftp-foreign error handling for nagios integration

Tags: perl, sftp, nagios

I am rather new in Perl. I have written a very simple script that copies and removes a file from sftp.

but the script should return some kind of output in order to integrate it with nagios.. using nsca or something.

the script is running on solaris 10.

here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $datestring =strftime "%d-%m-%Y", localtime;
my $host="sftp.mariog.com";
my $username="user";
my $local="/mnt/mariog";
my $file="BookingReport_Daily_$datestring.xls";

print "$file \n";

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host,
    user           => $username,
    stderr_discard => 1,
    autodie        => 1,
);
$sftp->die_on_error("unable to establish SFTP Connection");


$sftp->get("$file", "$local/$file");
$sftp->remove($file);
$sftp->disconnect();
```

how to handle the fact that the file does not exist on the sftp? maybe it has not reached yet. there a daily file uploaded but at different times. the script is run by cron every 4 hours so most of the times it will not find files to transfer...

where can I get the output code of the transfer successful or not? so that i can pass it to a nagios passive check with nsca...

thank you for your help..

kind regards.

Mario

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one way to check for a successful get in the documentation would be something like this:

```
$sftp->get("$file", "$local/$file") or die "get failed:" $sftp->error;
```

Comment: Hello
does not the autodie=1 in the constructor handles things? when I execute the script i get this:

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Couldn't stat remote file: No such file at ./datalex.pl line 20
        Net::SFTP::Foreign::Common::_ok_or_autodie('Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x80e1a24)') called at /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm line 1511
        Net::SFTP::Foreign::get('Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x80e1a24)', 'BookingReport_Daily_05-08-2014.xls', '/mnt/datalex/BookingReport_Daily_05-08-2014.xls') called at ./datalex.pl line 20.

Comment: I don't think so, but upon looking at your code again, you do appear to discard std_error in your constructor, too. you should probably not have that set to 1 if you want the errors

Comment: Hello,
If i do not put the discard std_err i alwasy get "killed by signal 15" at the end of script.. seems to be a problem with solaris. 
I do not want to have an error when the file is not there... i want to have errors when the file is there but transfer failed. is that even possible? I tried with eval...

Comment: Hm, not sure. I would also turn off autodie. Wrap the $sftp->get in an eval and check $@. I'm not sure if you can not have an error if the file is not there, though.

Comment: I have removed the autodie =>1.

Comment: i have made a test to check if the file is already in the local folder if so i do not download from sftp.
I still have an issue..if the daily file has not been uploaded to the sftp. the script  will die because the file will not be in the local folder and neither on the sftp. 
there is no difference between could not stat remove file and file transfer failed...it is the later one that interest me. 
thx